# Transferring from GoDaddy to Namecheap I'm getting, "Awaiting release from previous registrar."

Tags: domain-transfer

I have a domain on GoDaddy and I'm transferring it to Namecheap, during the process Namecheap shows this information,

> Domain is with another registrar.
>   Awaiting release from previous registrar.

How do I resolve this or expedite the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You're not done yet.

Log into GoDaddy and look for the *Pending Transfer* screen find the domain name and click `Accept/Decline` when this dialog pops up click *Accept*.

> **Accept or Decline**
>
> Confirm that you're accepting or declining the transfer of these domains to another registrar. Note: Domain transfer times may vary.